# Loop recursive through two files in perl

Tags: perl

Hi guys I have an issue to solve,

I have 2 files.

File A
col1,col2, value_total_to_put

```
File A 201843,12345,30
```

File B
col1,col2,col3, value_inputted, missing_value, value_max

```
201843,12345,447,4,0,4
201843,12345,448,0,0,4
201843,12345,449,0,0,2
201843,12345,450,4,0,4
201843,12345,451,2,0,2
201843,12345,455,4,0,4
201843,12345,457,0,0,4
201843,12345,899,10,0,10
201843,12345,334,0,1,1
201843,12345,364,0,1,1
201843,12345,71,0,2,2
201843,12345,260,0,2,2
201843,12345,321,0,2,2
201843,12345,328,0,2,2
201843,12345,371,0,2,2
201843,12345,385,0,2,2
201843,12345,426,0,2,2
201843,12345,444,0,2,2
201843,12345,31,4,6,10
201843,12345,360,2,87,99
201843,12345,373,4,95,99
201843,12345,472,4,95,99
201843,12345,475,4,95,99
201843,12345,430,0,99,99
201843,12345,453,0,99,99
201843,12345,463,0,99,99
201843,12345,482,0,99,99
201843,12345,484,0,99,99
```

My keys are col1 and col2 from both files and I am doing this way below and my loop is wrong because when I reach the EOF from File B my loop is stopped.
What I want is match File A and B with $col1 and $col2 and while the value_total_to_put is > 0 withdraw 1 in each loop and in value_inputted from File B when value_inputted is less than value_max. For withdraw from File A missing_value might be > 0.
For the result I will print when value_inputted is equal to value_max in other words the last value until reach value_max or value_total_to_put is 0.

```
while ( <FA> ){
        chomp;
        my($col1,$col2, $value_total_to_put) = split ",";
        push @A, [$col1,$col2, $value_total_to_put];
}

my @B;
while ( <FB> ){
        chomp;
        my($col1,$col2,$col3, $value_inputted, $missing_value, $value_max) = split ",";
        push @B, [$col1,$col2,$col3, $value_inputted, $missing_value, $value_max];
}


foreach my $line (@A){
        my $idxl = @$line[0].",".@$line[1];
        my $value_total_to_put = @$line[2];
        while ($value_total_to_put > 0){
                foreach my $row ( @B ){
                if ( $idxr eq $idxl ){
                        my $idxr = @$row[0].",".@$row[1];
                        my $value_inputted = @$row[3];
                        my $value_max = @$row[5];
                        my $missing_value = @$row[4];
                        if ( ($value_inputted eq 0) and ($missing_value eq 0)){
                                #do_nothing
                        } elsif($value_inputted == $value_max){
                                #do_nothing
                            print join(",", $idxr, @$row[2],"Value_inputted: ".$value_inputted, "Missing_value: ".$missing_value, "Value_max:".$value_max, "Total: ".$value_total_to_put)."\n";
                        }else{
                            $value_inputted++;
                            $missing_value--;
                            $value_total_to_put--;
                        }
                }
                }

        last if $value_total_to_put > 0;
        }
}
```

The third file will be this way:

```
201843,12345,447,4,0,4
201843,12345,450,4,0,4
201843,12345,451,2,0,2
201843,12345,455,4,0,4
201843,12345,899,10,0,10
201843,12345,334,1,0,1
201843,12345,364,1,0,1
201843,12345,71,2,0,2
201843,12345,260,2,0,2
201843,12345,321,2,0,2
201843,12345,328,2,0,2
201843,12345,371,2,0,2
201843,12345,385,2,0,2
201843,12345,426,2,0,2
201843,12345,444,2,0,2
201843,12345,31,10,0,10
201843,12345,360,3,86,99
201843,12345,373,5,94,99
201843,12345,472,5,94,99
201843,12345,475,5,94,99
201843,12345,430,1,98,99
201843,12345,453,1,98,99
```

Comment: We'll need some sample input data and the expected output that matches that data.

Comment: Oh right,
File A
201843,12345,30

Comment: File B
201843,12345,447,4,0,4
201843,12345,450,4,0,4
201843,12345,451,2,0,2
201843,12345,455,4,0,4
201843,12345,334,0,1,1
201843,12345,364,0,1,1
201843,12345,71,0,2,2
201843,12345,260,0,2,2
201843,12345,321,0,2,2
201843,12345,328,0,2,2
201843,12345,371,0,2,2
201843,12345,385,0,2,2
201843,12345,426,0,2,2
201843,12345,444,0,2,2
201843,12345,31,4,6,10
201843,12345,360,2,87,99
201843,12345,373,4,95,99
201843,12345,472,4,95,99
201843,12345,475,4,95,99
201843,12345,430,0,99,99
201843,12345,453,0,99,99
201843,12345,463,0,99,99
201843,12345,482,0,99,99
201843,12345,484,0,99,99

Comment: File Result
201843,12345,447,4,0,4
201843,12345,450,4,0,4
201843,12345,451,2,0,2
201843,12345,455,4,0,4
201843,12345,334,1,0,1
201843,12345,364,1,0,1
201843,12345,71,2,0,2
201843,12345,260,2,0,2
201843,12345,321,2,0,2
201843,12345,328,2,0,2
201843,12345,371,2,0,2
201843,12345,385,2,0,2
201843,12345,426,2,0,2
201843,12345,444,2,0,2
201843,12345,31,10,0,10
201843,12345,360,3,86,99
201843,12345,373,5,94,99
201843,12345,472,5,94,99
201843,12345,475,5,94,99
201843,12345,430,1,98,99
201843,12345,453,1,98,99

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53485089/edit) to add this information. Comments on StackOverflow are unformatted.

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: The question is still lacking clarity.  You mentioned files A and B, and a "third file" which I'm guessing is just the terminal output from your print statement that you plan to redirect.  In that case, you can call it "output" or "STDOUT".  Also your print statement has text labels for values whereas your "third file" doesn't.   You need to give a minimal and complete answer: a handful of lines for file A, B, and your intended output.

Comment: The result is basically the same file of second file the difference is the increment of value_inputted that have to reach the value_max or value_total_to_put is zero.

Comment: What do you think `@$line[0]` does? Because I strongly suspect you mean `$line->[0]`. Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code? Adding those and fixing all the problems they uncover would be a good start.

Comment: @$line[0] and @$line[1] are the col1 and col2 from each files. I use this way to match both files and I am using use strict and use warnings in my code. 
This is only a piece of my code.

Comment: *@$line[0] and @$line[1] are the col1 and col2 from each files* Yes, but my point is that this is a really non-standard way to write those expressions. More people would understand your code if you wrote them as `$line->[0]` and `$line->[1]`.

Comment: @ebk, is my below answer helpful ? Please let us know if you have somehow found a way to solve the issue

Comment: Actually, it was not what I was expecting, so I did it thinking in another way.
I'll put it below your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @Dave Cross, your code is quite hard to read (and misses `use strict`and `use warnings`), and your explanation of what you are trying to achieve is quite unclear...

One thing that caught my eye however, is that you start a loop with this statement...

```
while ($value_total_to_put > 0){
```

... but at the very end of that same block you do :

```
    last if $value_total_to_put > 0;
}
```

This will effectively cause Perl to exit the loop after the first iteration, no matter the value of the `$value_total_to_put` variable. This is probably not what you want. Hence, as far as I understand, you should start your investigation by removing that `last` statement.